# What is the relation between the size and resolution of HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is there a way by which I can create a canvas of large size but low resolution. I'm declaring the canvas with the syntax  `<canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="1000"></canvas>`. I'm running the above code on a 7 inch tablet and the canvas spans half of the screen of the canvas. Is there a way by which I can create a canvas which again covers half of the screen but has a lower resolution (lower quality of image).
Actually I draw something on the canvas and then save it as image by using canvas.toDataURL(). I don't need to get good quality image, but I want to lower the size of the image generated.

Forgive me if it's a silly question

Comment: HTML attributes (`width="700" height="1000"`) describe the *logical* size of the canvas, that is, how many pixels you can theoretically place in the canvas and adress individually. CSS properties (`canvas#mycanvas {width: 700px; height: 1000px;}`) describe the visual size of said canvas. The browser will stretch the canvas' logical pixels to fit in the visual area.

Answer (score 2):

First, scale your canvas element like this (in javascript):

```
    canvas.width=canvas1.width*scaleFactor;
    canvas.height=canvas1.height*scaleFactor;
```

Warning: If you scale the canvas using CSS, you will likely distort images drawn on the canvas

Then you can scale your image using some added arguments to `context.drawImage`

```
    var scaleFactor=0.50;

    ctx2.drawImage(img, 0,0,img.width,img.height,
                            0,0,img.width*scaleFactor,img.height*scaleFactor);
```

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6m8kg/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
    var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");

    var scaleFactor=0.50;

    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.onload=function(){

        // draw the image full-size on the larger canvas
        ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);

        // resize the canvas 
        // Don't use css to resize, it will distort your image
        // The scaling is done with the added drawImage arguements
        canvas2.width=canvas1.width*scaleFactor;
        canvas2.height=canvas1.height*scaleFactor;

        // draw a scaled-down image into the second canvas
        ctx2.drawImage(img, 0,0,img.width,img.height,
                            0,0,img.width*scaleFactor,img.height*scaleFactor);

    }
    img.src="faces.png";


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Top canvas is full-sized</p>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=400 height=242></canvas><br>
    <p>Bottom canvas is scaled down</p>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```